# How to convert a text string into hours

Tags: string, excel, text

I have data in the format as d.hh.mm.ss and hh.mm.ss and I need to conver both into a time value of HH.MM.SS

In A1 the text string is 16.21:38:27
in A2 the text string is    04:08:45

My resulting cell should show B1 405:38:27
                              B2  04:08:45

I have tried using  =LEFT(A1,SEARCH(":",A1)-1)+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH(":",A1)+1,255))
but the results are wrong
A1 is shown as 403:29:24
A2 is shown as 104:45:00

I would like one formula for both strings

Comment: I'm guessing this is Excel... added excel tag.

Comment: Your descrptions of your formats don't match the example values - is the "d" component followed by a period, or a colon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 4:08:45 is a valid time format and 16.21:38:27 is not this formula should work for you in both cases:

`=IF(ISNUMBER(A1+0),A1+0,RIGHT(A1,8)+LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1))`

format result cells as [h]:mm:ss

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
= IF(ISERROR(FIND(".",A1)),
    TIMEVALUE(A1), 
    VALUE(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1)-1)) + TIMEVALUE(MID(A1, FIND(".", A1)+1, 8)))
```

If a "." doesn't exist in the string, it simply uses TIMEVALUE() to parse the time. Otherwise, it parses the portion before and after the "." separately. The number of days forms the integer portion of the result, and the time is computed as a fractional day. This is then formatted using the standard formatting dialog into [h]:mm:ss format.

If you want B1 to store a *string* of the converted hours/minutes/seconds rather than a formatted number, wrap the whole of the above in `TEXT(formula above, "[h]:mm:ss")`.

Answer (score 0):

@TimWilliams hit the nail on the head. You have a typo. Change `16.21:38:27` to `16:21:38:27` and it will work fine. You can additionally wrap your formula to check the length. If it is more than 8 Chars then it means a date is added to it. See this example

Try this (You can use this for both)

`=IF(LEN(A1)>8,LEFT(A1,SEARCH(":",A1)-1)+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH(":",A1)+1,255)),TIMEVALUE(A1))`

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

**EDIT**

I just noticed that you have hardcoded `255` in your formula. You don't need to do that. This will also work.

`=IF(LEN(A1)>8,LEFT(A1,SEARCH(":",A1)-1)+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH(":",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH(":",A1)+1)),TIMEVALUE(A1))`

BTW, to make it foolproof you make also add the `TRIM` function to the above formula as well...